# How to return a path like p=(m)--(n)-[r]-(w), where r is optional in neo4j using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to return a path in neo4j ogm to get a object graph. In the path like the title figured out: `p=(m)--(n)-[r]-(w)`. Here r maybe exist or may be not. I want to return p not m, n, w.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a variable-length relationship between `n` and `w` with a minimum of 0.

Also, since you are only concerned with the path and aren't doing anything with the variables, you can omit them, they serve no purpose, though this kind of query, with no labels, properties, or relationship types restricting what you're looking for will match an awful lot of nodes on nearly any kind of graph.

```
MATCH p = ()--()-[*0..1]-()
RETURN p
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, something like

```
p=(m)--(n)-[r]-(w)
RETURN p
UNION
p=(m)--(n)
RETURN m,n,null,null
```